# Mean value of pixels nearest to point (per image per point of collections) (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, proximity

I'm trying to extract the nearest pixel value of an Image Collection. So, for a Feature Collection, I get a time series with the mean value of the nearest pixel.

The question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256758/nearest-pixel-value-from-point-dataset-google-earth-engine) shows how to do it for an Image, I would like to expand this to an Image Collection.

```
var point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-92.99620494440309, -37.40033329085335]),
    point2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-96.86339244440309, -41.668454262169]);

var start = ee.Date('2018-12-25');
var finish = ee.Date('2018-12-31');

var chla_collection= ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2018-12-25'),ee.Date('2018-12-31'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a local function of the answer provided by Noel, and use that function when you map over each single image of the image collection.

As you use multiple images and multiple features in the input, the output will consist of a collection of collections. `flatten()` the result to get single features. It's probably a good idea to give the points an individual ID or some kind of property so you can later find the values of each point using a filter.

Define a function of the function provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256758/nearest-pixel-value-from-point-dataset-google-earth-engine):

```
// Local function to calculate the value of the nearest pixel
function calcValNearestPixel(IMAGE, Points) {
  var distance = IMAGE.fastDistanceTransform().sqrt()
                           .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().sqrt()).rename("distance");
  Points = distance.reduceRegions(Points, ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(["distance"]))
    .map(function(f) {
      var distance = ee.Number(f.get('distance'));
      f = ee.Algorithms.If(distance, 
          f.buffer(distance.add(pixelSize), 1),
          f);
      f = ee.Feature(f);
      return f.set(IMAGE.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().unweighted(), 
                                        geometry: f.geometry(), 
                                        scale: pixelSize,
                                        maxPixels: 10e8,
      }));
    });
return Points;
}
```

Map over the images and apply the function to each image of the collection:

```
// map over the image collection and get value of the nearest points  
var nearestMeanValues = chla_collection.map(function(image){
  return calcValNearestPixel(image, pts);
}).flatten();

print(nearestMeanValues)
```

See the [link to the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/495130c570cfb61c477db8ec273f4deb)

Comment: Just a note to everyone reading - this answer and the [function described](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264402/68792) are a neat way to deal with masked values in a point times series if you don't mind relying on unmasked neighboring pixels. Note, however, that you could end up including pixels that are a far distance from the point(s).

Comment: Well Noel nicely added the actual distance from the point, so you could easily filter on something like a maximum distance.

Comment: Where would be the place to filter the image collection by the bounds of my study region? I get the error "too many pixels". But my actual study area is quite small and I'm only interested in distances within the boundaries of a specific geometry. I tried to do it as var distance=IMAGE.filterBounds(X) .... but doesn't work. I get the error IMAGE.filterBounds(X) is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value for the pixel actually intersecting the point (even if masked), here is a solution similar to Kuik's. Note that point ID and image ID are carried into the final feature collection.

```js
// Define points.
var point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-92.99620494440309, -37.40033329085335]),
    point2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-96.86339244440309, -41.668454262169]);

// Define image dates of interest.
var start = ee.Date('2018-12-25');
var finish = ee.Date('2018-12-31');

// Filter image collection to dates of interest.
var chla_collection= ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2018-12-25'),ee.Date('2018-12-31'));

// Make a feature collection from points - provide IDs.  
var pointFc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(point1, {pointID: 0}),
  ee.Feature(point2, {pointID: 1})
]);

// Extract value for pixels intersection points per image.
var intersectingValue = chla_collection.map(function(img) {
  return img.reduceRegions({
    collection: pointFc, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    scale: 500
  })
  // Add image ID as feature property.
  .map(function(feature) {
    return feature.set('imgID', img.id());
  });
});

print(intersectingValue.flatten());
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5fda116925c62bdb9cb2dc17c290583e)

Comment: Thanks Justin. Given the nature of the real data interesection is not as important as nearest pixel. Indeed, I have very few interesctions (because points are very near the shore, which is not the case in this sample data, but in the real one).